# ISO 233-2 transliteration of wāw-ʾalif grammatical ending in Arabic

Tags: arabic, transliteration, standards

My question concerns the ISO-233-2:1993 transliteration of Arabic, and specifically of the grammatical ending wāw-ʾalif such as is found in the conjugation of verbs, e.g., “⁧فَعَلُوا⁩” (”they did”).  As far as I know, the final ʾalif is purely orthographic and is not pronounced.  If I am not mistaken, in ISO-233:1984, which follows the Arabic script verbatim, this would be transcribed “faʿaluwʾ”, but in ISO-233-2:1993 where the vowels are transcribed in a simplified form, we would get “faʿalū” ignoring this final ʾalif: my question is whether it should, indeed, be ignored in transcription or whether it should be marked in some way.

(I don't have access to the ISO standard itself.)

Answer (score 2):

I finally found [this page](https://kitcat.bnf.fr/consignes-catalogage/translitteration-de-larabe) which is an internal document of the *Bibliothèque Nationale de France* indicating how they use ISO 233-2 as well as (in section 6) some complements thereon.  Paragaph 6.4 concerns the orthographical ʾalif which I was asking about in this question.  It states:

> Le cas de l’alif orthographique final (mādīou accompli 3e personne du pluriel) n’est pas envisagé par la norme ISO 233-2 (1993). Il n’est pas prononcé et n’est pas restitué en translittération.
> Exemple : فتحوا => fataḥū

Or, in English (translation mine):

> The case of final orthographical alif (mādīou 3rd person plural accomplished) is not considered by the ISO 233-2 (1993) norm.  It is not pronounced and not marked in transliteration.  Example: فتحوا => fataḥū

So it appears that ISO 233-2 forgot(?) to consider this case, and that the *BNF* decided to simply omit the letter in transliteration, as I was suggesting.